# Converting nested Hibernate Search 5 predicates to Hibernate Search 6

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

In the process of converting an application from Hibernate Search 5 to 6.  I've read thru much of the documentation, especially https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#queries-reference
on how to convert Query DSL and I understand it in a simple scenario but how would you nest predicates into other nested predicates, and then combine those with others in a larger query?
In Hibernate Search 5 we would use queryBuilder.bool() to create a BooleanJunction that you could then add inside another BooleanJunction by calling createQuery on the bool and do that over and over creating nested predicate queries.

Example of the type of code I'm talking about converting:

```
    BooleanJunction vendorNameBool = queryBuilder.bool();
    BooleanJunction nameBool = queryBuilder.bool();
    
    nameBool.must(
        qb.keyword()
            .onField(CompanyName)
            .matching(nameToken1)
            .createQuery()
    );
    
    nameBool.must(
        qb.keyword()
            .onField(CompanyName)
            .matching(nameToken2)
            .createQuery()
    );

    vendorNameBool.should(nameBool.createQuery);
    
    // do vendorNameBool.should(...) for as many vendor Names that exist, then createQuery 
    probableVendorNamesQuery = vendorNameBool.createQuery();
    
    // creating a number of Queries from various bools and then combining them:
    Query taxIdOrVendorNameOrPhoneNumberQuery = qb.bool()
        .should(probableVendorNamesQuery)
        .should(taxIdQuery)
        .should(phoneNumberQuery)
        .createQuery();
        
    //and add to the final BooleanQuery along with other Query pieces
    
    Query idQuery = getIdQuery();
    Query fileIdQuery = getFileIdQuery();
    
    BooleanQuery.Builder theQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    theQuery.add(taxIdOrVendorNameOrPhoneNumberQuery, MUST);
    theQuery.add(fileIdQuery, MUST);    
    theQuery.add(idQuery, MUST_NOT);    
    
    BooleanQuery probableQuery = theQuery.build();
     
    // add some projections and execute query
```

Most of the HS6 code examples are in lambda form. There is a section [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#queries-basics) that provides a simple example of creating a non-lamba predicate, adding them to a list, but how, for example, would you then add that list of predicates to an outer *should* clause, and then add that *should* clause, along with another *should* clause, to an outer "must" clause, etc. etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd just go with the lambda syntax and nest a second lambda. Adapting the example from the migration guide:

```java
 MySearchParameters searchParameters = ...;
 SearchSession session = Search.session( entityManager );
 List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
         .where( f -> f.bool( b -> {
             b.must( f.matchAll() );
             if ( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() != null ) {
                 b.must( f.simpleQueryString().fields( "title", "description" )
                         .matching( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() )
                         .defaultOperator( BooleanOperator.AND ) );
             }
             // ...
             // BEGIN NEW CODE
             SomeComplexParameter complexParam = searchParameters.getSomeComplexParameter();
             if ( complexParam != null ) {
                 b.must( f.bool( b2 -> {
                     b2.should( f.match().field( "someField1" )
                         .matching( complexParam.getSomeField1() ) );
                     b2.should( f.match().field( "someField2" )
                         .matching( complexParam.getSomeField2() ) );
                 } ) );
             }
             // END NEW CODE
         } ) )
         .fetchHits( params.getPageIndex() * params.getPageSize(), params.getPageSize() );
```

You don't even need a second lambda if you know the number of clauses at compile time:

```java
 MySearchParameters searchParameters = ...;
 SearchSession session = Search.session( entityManager );
 List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
         .where( f -> f.bool( b -> {
             b.must( f.matchAll() );
             if ( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() != null ) {
                 b.must( f.simpleQueryString().fields( "title", "description" )
                         .matching( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() )
                         .defaultOperator( BooleanOperator.AND ) );
             }
             // ...
             // BEGIN NEW CODE
             SomeComplexParameter complexParam = searchParameters.getSomeComplexParameter();
             if ( complexParam != null ) {
                 b.must( f.bool()
                         .should( f.match().field( "someField1" )
                             .matching( complexParam.getSomeField1() ) )
                         .should( f.match().field( "someField2" )
                             .matching( complexParam.getSomeField2() ) ) );
             }
             // END NEW CODE
         } ) )
         .fetchHits( params.getPageIndex() * params.getPageSize(), params.getPageSize() );
```

If you really don't want to use lambdas at the top level (why?), you could use lambdas for nested predicates, at least:

```java
MySearchParameters searchParameters = ...;
SearchSession session = Search.session( entityManager );
SearchPredicateFactory pf = session.scope( Book.class ).predicate();
List<SearchPredicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

if ( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() != null ) {
    predicates.add( pf.simpleQueryString().fields( "title", "description" )
            .matching( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() )
            .defaultOperator( BooleanOperator.AND )
            .toPredicate() );
}

// ...

// BEGIN NEW CODE
SomeComplexParameter complexParam = searchParameters.getSomeComplexParameter();
if ( complexParam != null ) {
    predicates.add( pf.bool( b -> {
        b.should( pf.match().field( "someField1" )
            .matching( complexParam.getSomeField1() ) );
        b.should( pf.match().field( "someField2" )
            .matching( complexParam.getSomeField2() ) );
    } )
            .toPredicate() );
}
// END NEW CODE

List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool( b -> {
            b.must( f.matchAll() );
            for ( SearchPredicate predicate : predicates ) {
                b.must( predicate );
            }
        } )
```

And here too, you don't need a lambda as long as you know the number of predicates in advance:

```java
MySearchParameters searchParameters = ...;
SearchSession session = Search.session( entityManager );
SearchPredicateFactory pf = session.scope( Book.class ).predicate();
List<SearchPredicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

if ( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() != null ) {
    predicates.add( pf.simpleQueryString().fields( "title", "description" )
            .matching( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() )
            .defaultOperator( BooleanOperator.AND )
            .toPredicate() );
}

// ...

// BEGIN NEW CODE
SomeComplexParameter complexParam = searchParameters.getSomeComplexParameter();
if ( complexParam != null ) {
    predicates.add( pf.bool()
            .should( pf.match().field( "someField1" )
                .matching( complexParam.getSomeField1() ) )
            .should( pf.match().field( "someField2" )
                 .matching( complexParam.getSomeField2() ) )
            .toPredicate() );
}
// END NEW CODE

List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool( b -> {
            b.must( f.matchAll() );
            for ( SearchPredicate predicate : predicates ) {
                b.must( predicate );
            }
        } )
        .fetchHits( params.getPageIndex() * params.getPageSize(), params.getPageSize() );
```

Finally, if you really want to completely stay away from lambdas (but again, why?), you can probably do something like this. Be aware that the generic type parameters of `BooleanPredicateClausesStep` might change in a minor version of Hibernate Search, though, so this code is more likely to break when upgrading.

```java
MySearchParameters searchParameters = ...;
SearchSession session = Search.session( entityManager );
SearchPredicateFactory pf = session.scope( Book.class ).predicate();
BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> boolStep = pf.bool();

boolStep.must( f.matchAll() );

if ( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() != null ) {
    boolStep.must( pf.simpleQueryString().fields( "title", "description" )
            .matching( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() )
            .defaultOperator( BooleanOperator.AND ) );
}

// ...

SomeComplexParameter complexParam = searchParameters.getSomeComplexParameter();
if ( complexParam != null ) {
    BooleanPredicateClausesStep<?> boolStep2 = pf.bool();
    boolStep2.should( f.match().field( "someField1" )
            .matching( complexParam.getSomeField1() ) );
    boolStep2.should( f.match().field( "someField2" )
            .matching( complexParam.getSomeField2() ) );
    boolStep.must( boolStep2 );
}

SearchPredicate boolPredicate = boolStep.toPredicate();

List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( boolPredicate )
        .fetchHits( params.getPageIndex() * params.getPageSize(), params.getPageSize() );
```

If you're compiling with JDK 11, a more robust solution would be to use the `var` keyword:

```java
MySearchParameters searchParameters = ...;
SearchSession session = Search.session( entityManager );
SearchPredicateFactory pf = session.scope( Book.class ).predicate();
var boolStep = pf.bool();

boolStep.must( f.matchAll() );

if ( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() != null ) {
    boolStep.must( pf.simpleQueryString().fields( "title", "description" )
            .matching( searchParameters.getSearchTerms() )
            .defaultOperator( BooleanOperator.AND ) );
}

// ...

SomeComplexParameter complexParam = searchParameters.getSomeComplexParameter();
if ( complexParam != null ) {
    var boolStep2 = pf.bool();
    boolStep2.should( f.match().field( "someField1" )
            .matching( complexParam.getSomeField1() ) );
    boolStep2.should( f.match().field( "someField2" )
            .matching( complexParam.getSomeField2() ) );
    boolStep.must( boolStep2 );
}

SearchPredicate boolPredicate = boolStep.toPredicate();

List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( boolPredicate )
        .fetchHits( params.getPageIndex() * params.getPageSize(), params.getPageSize() );
```

Comment: I think your last suggestion will do the trick. Lambdas work great if you have all your match criteria in a single location. Our logic builds reusable bools/predicates which then get incorporated into further upstream bools/predicates. The logic is spread out in a number of methods.
It's possible your 2nd suggestion group would work also. We do know the number of predicates in advance, but need to be able to return predicates from 1 method to use in another, and to nest some predicates. In that suggestion, can you return the list of predicates from a method and use in calling method?

Comment: Or does that leave you having to use BooleanPredicateClausesStep again?

Comment: You can perfectly well use helper methods with lambdas: just make sure their signature is something like `PredicateFinalStep myHelper(SearchPredicateFactory f, <other params>)`. Then you can call `.must( myHelper( f, <other params> ) )`. If you need the helper to return multiple predicates, I would have the helper itself call `f.bool().should(<predicate 1>).should(<predicate 2>)` and return the result. You don't need a list when you have boolean predicates.